# How to create zip file in Magento 2.1 to create a downloadable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, downloadable, download-link, zip

I am new to Magento. I want to create Books and Audio Books store in Magento 2.1.

I need to create configurable products as a simple product (Book) & a downloadable Product (Audio Book).

The mp3 Audio Book files should be downloadable as a zip file for the customer once the payment received.

Please let me know how to achieve this?

**Edited :** I need to create all the files located in the web link into a zip file so that customers can download after the **Buy** button clicked.

Comment: Why would you want to create a ZIP-file? Why not just upload the ZIP-file to your store and attach it to your product? Seems a bit like a hassle to have the store to create ZIP-files.

Comment: Hi, @GielBerkers! Thank you for your response! We have hundreds of products I'm thinking it would be a good idea to keep zipping for every product we have automatically when a customer ordered.